# Как сделать поисковую выдачу на сайте, чтобы она работала не только по количеству лайков под постом, но и по их качеству?

Tags: алгоритм, веб-программирование, поиск

Лайки УЖЕ коррелируются с просмотрами и частотой их поступления.
То есть у меня уже НЕ самый примитивный алгоритм.

Но все равно, можно нарегать тысячи аккаунтов, накрутить с каждого по лайку, и показатель получится выше, чем у многих честных лидеров.

Comment: А как вы делали до сих пор?

Comment: @0xdb Выше же написано. Кол-во лайков, кол-во просмотров и частота их поступления.

Comment: "но и по их качеству?" как минимум стоит привести критерии качества, качественный это какой? самый большой лайки, самый лайкнутый лайк, может самый добрый или самый четкий, от четких пацанов...

Comment: @Виктор лайк не от ботов.

Comment: "лайк не от ботов" тогда просто посчитайте сколько лайков от не ботов и на этом стройте рейтинг, все просто =)

Comment: @Виктор Так какие варианты отличить не ботов от ботов? 6 комментов уже, а все вокруг да окол

Comment: вы так и не дали точное определение бота

Comment: @Виктор а как бы я его дал? не я же эти боты пишу

Comment: Накрутка может быть разная, как в автоматическом режиме (левые аккаунты + автоматические лайки), так и в ручном (свои/покупные аккаунты + автоматические/ручные лайки) + в любой другой комбинации + разные ip + заказные на биржах. Алгоритм, который вы хотите разрабатывают целые компании и не всегда успешно, при этом разработки держутся в секрете, чтобы сервисы по накрутке не обходили их.